# Spring default implementation of command design pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-boot

Is there any default command design pattern implementation in Spring framework? I want to avoid implementing additional director and interfaces if there is any default one.

I tried to look it up but everybody has its own custom implementation. There is `ApplicationEvent` class which you can extend and create custom events, I'm searching for something like that for different design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there isn't.

I can see where you might think the `ApplicationEvent` publishing system is somewhat like the *Command* pattern but I'd prefer to say that its much more closely aligned with the *Observer* pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of the [Command Pattern](https://springframework.guru/gang-of-four-design-patterns/command-pattern/) in Java is the [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, more recently augmented with the [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface.